# How to replicate powershell pipeline for file system objects in python

Tags: python, pipeline

I'm making the transition to Python from PowerShell and Javscript and am wondering how I can replicate the PowerShell pipeline in Python. In powershell, you can easily write a command that accepts file system entities (files and/or diretories) and then sends that back out to the pipeline. So you can compose a pipeline with various different commands. The concept of a pipeline is nothing new to linux/python, I am just trying to figure out the best Pythonic way of doing this.

In Python, we have the standard command [os.scandir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir), which returns an iterator of os.DirEntry objects. But how to we send these down a pipeline and also read these instances from the pipeline? Is there a standard way of doing this kind of thing, perhaps a standard command of which I am not yet aware (even after having searched for one).

What I'm ultimately looking for is a way of writing python functions that can be chained together via the pipeline that can accept a collection of files/directories process them in some way, then send them out to the pipeline, in a fashion similar to PowerShell. In PowerShell, files/directories are represented by objects (System.IO.FileSystemInfo), so this interface is clear, in Python this is a mystery to me. Perhaps between different commands, the interface would simply be files/directories represented by text, that would have to processed by regular expressions or some other functionality.

Actually, to be clear, I'm not necessarily interested in piping the contents of a file, more just the meta data that represents the file, ie the os.DirEntry instance.

Thanks.

Comment: "How to re-implement another programming language on a runtime with a different kind of type system" feels a bit broad for StackOverflow... For reference, the core PowerShell API (S.M.A.) consists of half a million lines of code :)

Comment: Sorry I don't what you mean. This questions seems quite staright forward, just need to to know python specifics which I have so far not found in the documentation. It maybe there is no python idiomatic way of doing ths and that would be fine. All I'm trying to do is not re-invent the wheel

Comment: Is your question specifically about using pipeline-like syntax to chain functions together, e.g. `function_c = function_a | function_b` rather than `def function_c(some_input): return function_b(function_a(some_input))`?

Comment: No. I already know about syntax. I'm interested in implementation. Perhaps with streams? I just want to know if they is a standard way of doing this in Python before I invent a whole new frameworkto do this.

Comment: fwiw, what I was getting at is using pickle to serialise os.direntry objects and then send them to another process via os.pipe. Should be able to create a pipeline from these 2 concepts

Comment: Can you give more details on what you are trying to achieve? Python doesn't have anything called a "pipeline", so it's difficult to understand. Why are you serializing direntry objects rather than just communicating within the same process? Are you able to write code that has the effect that you're looking for but would prefer to make it more powershell-like, or have you made no progress? If you have something, please post it here and explain why it is inadequate.

Comment: HI @Oli, in linux, you can do something like dir <path> | grep "blah". This is a genral concept copied by PowerShell, except objects are sent between different processes via stin/stdout. This is what I'm trying to achieve in Python. Its a powerful thing to be able to write different apps, and then connect them via piping. I believe I can achieve this using pickle to serialise os.direntry objects and then read/write to stdin/stdout streams. That is the basis I'm going forward on, but the point of me asking the question was to to find out if there was a standard python way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: By using this tehnique, I can write python commands that integrate with existing linux tools that people already know how to use. Eg, the linux find command is very powerful, I wouldnt want to re-write a find command. Rather I would like for a user to be able to invoke "find <parameters> | my_python_command <other-parameters> | another_python-command". I hope you understand where I'm coming from now.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. If you want to read and write to stdin and stdout, just use the built-in `input` and `print` functions, unless you want to do more advanced I/O, in which case you may need the `sys.stdin.read(my_char_count)` function for reading a specific number of characters or the `sys.stdin.buffer` stream for reading bytes rather than strings (after importing the `sys` module). `sys.stdout.buffer` is also available for writing bytes.

Comment: Ok thanks @Oli, that’s helpful cheers :)

Comment: If you want to run other programs inside python, I recommend the `subprocess` module, especially here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#replacing-shell-pipeline